# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and then don't use the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, uikit

If I call:

```
-[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier]
```

and then I choose **not** to reuse the cell in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is a leak necessarily introduced? My guess is that it would be `dealloced` as soon as the autorelease pool drains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an autoreleased object, and will not cause a memory leak.

But if you choose not to reuse cells (for whatever reason), then there is no need to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` first.

*Update:* You can check how many cells are stored in the internal reuse queue with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *reuseDict = [self.tableView valueForKey:@"reusableTableCells"];
NSArray *reuseArray = [reuseDict objectForKey:CellIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%d", [reuseArray count]);
```

I tested this with the Master-Detail Xcode application, where I had removed the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. The number of cells in the reuse queue increased to a maximum of 17 in landscape orientation and 23 in portrait. This was exactly the number of visible cells plus one. So the number is indeed limited, even if you never reuse cells.

Comment: I thought that if I don't call dequeue then the cells remain enqueued and that's a leak... hmmm...

Comment: @Yar: OK, yes, the table view will store some cells for reuse, but I assume that the number is limited.

Comment: @Yar: It is almost 2 years ago that I wrote this answer :) I am sure convinced of its correctness when writing it, but I did not think about it since then.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit behind on my inbox ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this introduces a leak. Try this empirically by subclassing `UITableViewCell`:

```
static int instances = 0;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"Init! instances=%d", instances++);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc! instances=%d", --instances);
}
```

If you don't use the cell that comes back from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you will have a leak.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Use the results of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` as you're supposed to or
2. Use `nil` as the `reuseIdentifier`; then no leak will be introduced. This is the best solution unless your table has a lot of rows, and you don't want to deal with the mess of reuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not return UITableViewCell returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` then it might create a leak or not depending on what you are doing. Cells returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` are automatically released when table view is released because table view is holding a reference to every cell returned by this method.

You will have a problem if for example you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` repeatedly in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    // calculate height
    // ...
}
```

In above code `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will always return new cell everytime this method is called so memory usage will rise when you scroll the table view. However at some later point in time these cells allocated by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will be automatically released when table view is realeased.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not cause a leak, but will not necessarily be memory efficient either. If you wish to have all these cell reuse chores handled automatically for you, consider using a framework such as the excellent Sensible TableView (free).